# nginx - rewrite location to root of server

Tags: nginx

I have this `nginx.conf` nginx configuration:

```
http {    
    ...

    upstream app_servers {
        server admin;
    }
    upstream status_servers {
        server status:5000;
    }

    # Configuration for the server
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://app_servers;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
        location /api {
            proxy_pass         http://api_servers;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
    }
}
```

- `/` is server to one server, and
- `/api` to another api server.

The problem is with the second (the api server).

The calls are reaching `/api/**` while I want them to reach the root of the api server (basically remove the /api when calling the api server).

so calling

- `/api`     -> will reach `/` in the api server, and calling
- `/api/foo` -> will reach `/foo` in the api server.

I guess I'm looking for some kind of rewrite rull for that(?)

I have tried Inside the `/api` location:

```
rewrite ^/api(.*) /$1 last;
```

but it didn't seem to work.

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it using `rewrite ^/api(/.*)$ $1 break;`

but I can't just using `/api` - it must be `/api/` (with trailing `/`)

For me it's fine, interesting though if anyone knows how to have support for `/api` too.

Comment: seems it regex pattern, so the trail slash

Comment: Any idea how to support `/api`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you still need it...but I managed to avoid "/api/", by doing this:

```
rewrite /api(/|$)(.*) /$2 break;
```